# Collapsing rows with consecutive ranges in two separate columns

Tags: r, duplicates, range, aggregate

I would very much appreciate your help on this one. I'm trying to condense a data frame of 200,000+ rows, where the integer of one row in column "start" is the exact to the next consecutive row in column "end". For reference, these are chromosomal base pair positions, and an example code below:

```
genomic_ranges <- data.frame(sample_ID = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "C"),
                         start = c(1, 20, 30, 40, 250),
                         end =  c(5, 30, 40, 70, 400),
                         feature = c("normal", "DUP", "DUP", "DUP", "DUP"))
```

```
sample_ID start end feature
1         A     1   5  "normal"
2         B    20  30     "DUP"
3         B    30  40     "DUP"
4         B    40  70     "DUP"
5         C   250 400     "DUP"
```

I have tried logical vectors, boolean operators, ifelse statements, forloops etc, I can't find a way to 1)delete the rows showing middle ranges, and 2)paste together the 1st and last rows which contain the true start and end position of the range.

Some of what I've tried:

```
ifelse(cnv_catalogue_final$end == cnv_catalogue_final$start, "to_delete", "other"))
cnv_catalogue_final$end %in% cnv_catalogue_final$start
dplyr::filter(slice_min(start, x) | slice_max(end, x))
```

Even if I use something like this `(StartA <= EndB)  and  (EndA >= StartB)` I'll still be loosing either the start or end position.

*Edit: thank you all for your feedback! I've updated the question with code. These rows do have ID's identified by sample_ID. Ideally, I would like 1 row with the complete range of 20-70, instead of it being cut into segments of 20-30, 30-40, and 40-70, in 3 rows with the same sample_ID identifier.

Comment: You might want to tag the language you're using.

Comment: Please share the data with ```dput()``` and avoid sharing pictures for the table.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by middle ranges? do these rows have IDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this, here is one:

```
library(tidyverse)
genomic_ranges %>%
  group_by(sample_ID) %>%
  summarize(start = min(start),
            end = max(end),
            feature = feature[1])
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  sample_ID start   end feature
  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
1 A             1     5 normal 
2 B            20    70 DUP    
3 C           250   400 DUP
```

Comment: Thats elegantly simple! Thank you for your answer @deschen!

Answer (score 0):

After much searching, trial/error, and chatting with colleagues, I've found another way to collapse ranges, and per usual its a much simple solution that I expected. I simply used valr package's bed_merge() function.

This is specific for genomic ranges (bed_merge() needs chromosome numbers - built in specificity yay!), and is particularly helpful when the only unique identifier between samples is the range. Grouping by sample_ID is still necessary because ranges can overlap between samples. Only down side is that this function doesn't preserve any additional data in your df, so a key would be useful to make to merge your metadata and ranges.

Here is an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(valr)
df <- data.frame(sample_ID = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
                 chrom = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 start = c(1, 20, 30, 40, 70, 90, 100, 110, 130, 250),
                 end =  c(5, 30, 40, 70, 80, 100, 110, 130, 150, 400),
                 feature = c("normal", "DUP", "DUP", "DUP", "DUP", "DUP", "DUP", "DUP", "DUP", "DUP"))

> df    
   sample_ID chrom start end feature
1          A     1     1   5  normal
2          B     1    20  30     DUP
3          B     1    30  40     DUP
4          B     1    40  70     DUP
5          B     1    70  80     DUP
6          B     1    90 100     DUP
7          B     1   100 110     DUP
8          B     1   110 130     DUP
9          C     1   130 150     DUP
10         C     1   250 400     DUP



collapsed_df <- df %>%
  group_by(sample_ID) %>%
  bed_merge()

> collapsed_df
# A tibble: 5 × 4
# Groups:   sample_ID [3]
  sample_ID chrom start   end
  <chr>     <dbl> <int> <int>
1 A             1     1     5
2 B             1    20    80
3 B             1    90   130
4 C             1   130   150
5 C             1   250   400
```